# Search Query Results Showing Folders

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, search-express

Recently there was a problem with the SharePoint Search Application service, so a new one was created (old one still exists temporarily).  Since we recreated the service, however, we have noticed odd behaviors.  One search page, for example, is now only displaying folders.  No results are displayed.  The core results web part is using location visualization and default XSL.  In fact, nothing on this search page was changed after new search service app was created other than changing scope name to point to new search service app scope.  But scope on both old and new search apps are identical.

Anyone have an idea why this is displaying like this?  And is there any way to show results with default settings?

***FYI*** I have also noticed this is occuring, though in smaller batches, on all site searches.  I performed a search and there are some XML entries showing a folder with no detail.

[image: Search Results]

I temporarily changed the raw XML output of core search results, and the folders are showing the following data:

```
<Result>
  <id>1</id>
  <workid>181</workid>
  <rank>78054684</rank>
  <title></title>
  <author></author>
  <size></size>
  <url></url>
  <urlEncoded></urlEncoded>
  <description></description>
  <write></write>
  <sitename></sitename>
  <collapsingstatus>0</collapsingstatus>
  <hithighlightedsummary />
  <hithighlightedproperties />
  <contentclass></contentclass>
  <isdocument></isdocument>
  <picturethumbnailurl></picturethumbnailurl>
  <popularsocialtags />
  <picturewidth></picturewidth>
  <pictureheight></pictureheight>
  <datepicturetaken></datepicturetaken>
  <serverredirectedurl></serverredirectedurl>
  <fileextension></fileextension>
  <imageurl imageurldescription="Folder">/_layouts/images/folder.gif</imageurl>
</Result>
```

This is obviously different than the XML data from a valid search result item

```
<Result>
  <id>8</id>
  <workid>71120</workid>
  <rank>70789420</rank>
  <title>TITLE OF PAGE</title>
  <author></author>
  <size>0</size>
  <url>LINK OF PAGE</url>
  <urlEncoded>ENCODED URL OF PAGE</urlEncoded>
  <description></description>
  <write></write>
  <sitename>SITE NAME OF PAGE</sitename>
  <collapsingstatus>0</collapsingstatus>
  <hithighlightedsummary>SUMMARY PULLED FROM PAGE<ddd /> </hithighlightedsummary>
  <hithighlightedproperties>
    <HHTitle>TITLE</HHTitle>
    <HHUrl>URL</HHUrl>
  </hithighlightedproperties>
  <contentclass></contentclass>
  <isdocument>True</isdocument>
  <picturethumbnailurl></picturethumbnailurl>
  <popularsocialtags />
  <picturewidth>0</picturewidth>
  <pictureheight>0</pictureheight>
  <datepicturetaken></datepicturetaken>
  <serverredirectedurl></serverredirectedurl>
  <fileextension>PHP</fileextension>
  <imageurl imageurldescription="Item icon">/_layouts/images/generaldocument.gif</imageurl>
</Result>
```

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find a solution? I've got the same problem.